# Excel - transpose three rows into 3 columns with multiple extra data

Tags: excel, dataset, rows, transpose

I'm struggling to find this elsewhere in the forum - please do point me in the right direction if I've missed it.
I'm trying to do a transpose of a large data set that has 3 rows per item and I want 1 row with 3 columns instead.

Here's an example:

[image: Excel table 1]

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image: Excel table 2]

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction on how to achieve this, please?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Using Power Query, pivot on the relationship column with Name as the value and No aggregation.

Comment: Thanks, Ron - how does one use Power Query?

Comment: Power Query is native in Office 365. On the Excel Data tab, select Get Data From Table or Range while your cursor is in your data range. I recommend finding a YouTube video on unpivoting data before you get started. Try Excel Is Fun for good examples. It'll be worth the time.

Comment: Available in Excel 2010+. Built-in in later versions as `Data=>Get&Transform`

Comment: Thank you both - I'll look into this Power Query.